How to find the image of an object in case of a tilted spherical mirror?
Problem
A lens is used to obtain real image of a point(/small object) at $(75,0)$. This acts as the virtual object for a convex mirror of radius of curvature $100cm$ placed at $(50,0)$ tilted at $30°$ to negative x-axis. Find coordinates of image formed by mirror.
This is part of this complete question with my teachers solution :

My attempt
This was my attempt at the solution:

Since the mirror axis is tilted, the point object maybe treated as the tip/head of an extended object. Then the head/tip of image gives the coordinates of the image of point object. However my answers don't match with his answers or options.
Question
He says that I am making a simple thing  far too complicated. That since rotation of spherical mirror,by $\theta$ rotates reflected rays by $2\theta$ the image is formed at the distance if mirror weren't tilted but at an angle $2\theta$ . He didn't explain why I was wrong and I don't think that rotation of reflected ray means rotation of image by same amount without any other change

What is the correct way to locate image of point object if spherical mirror is tilted/rotated by some angle?
Why is my method wrong?


The "teacher's solution" is more complicated than it needs to be. Consider a flat mirror and how it reflects. For this problem consider the circular mirror as if it were made of tiny flat mirrors. Your method seems to be treating the mirror as a lens of some sort...?

Not exactly. Convex mirror always forms virtual image for real object. So it forms real image for virtual object. I simply took the point object as tip of  extended object  because it allows me to apply mirror formula and mirror magnification formula and trigonometry, easily

Well, if you ever get a chance to have a mirror, laser safety glasses, and a laser pointer, you may learn that how reflection works is closer to what the "teacher's solution" implies. They're basically asking where the laser pointer's lens image ends up when reflected, and it's definitely going to be along where the laser dot ends up if turned on. I've got no interest in understanding an "always" model that conflicts with reality so this one's for someone else.

@Abel Now you have confused me. I clearly understand the laster pointer analogy. But if there was a dot/spot on a piece of paper and that was used, the theory should hold right? Besides if the theory holds for extended objects why doesn’t it hold for points whose integration the extended object is? Why even teach that theory for years under the name "Mirror Formula", "Tranverse Magnification" if fails in simple case?
